# Is there a visual editor specifically for page snippets/sections?

Tags: plugins, php, visual-editor

I am building a Wordpress/Woocommerce site, and developing a plugin for it.

In the plugin I am including some PHP html templates and hooking them into Wordpress in various ways.

Is there a way to visually compose and store these page snippets/sections somehow so that they can be viewed and edited in admin, through a visual composer?

I am envisioning something like Wordpress' page designer/editor, except just for page sections/snippets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that this can be done simply by using Wordpress' Page editor. Nothing else is needed:

1. Compose the content in Wordpress' Page editor
2. Save (*but don't publish*)
3. In your code, retrieve the saved content

[By ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318869/3207129):

```
$id=47;
$post = get_post($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;
```

[Or by page title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895034/3207129):

```
$title = 'page title';
$page = get_page_by_title( $title );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo $content;
```

Note that apply_filters is used in case there is a plugin somewhere that wants to "apply filters" to the_content - it's good for forwards compatibility.